# Move Google Chrome close/minimize/maximize buttons to the left side

Tags: release-loki, google-chrome

The OS naturally puts the "close" buttons on the left, but `chrome` does not obey. Chrome's "Use system title bar" option just add the usual system bar above the Chrome window but I wanted the button section to remain in-line with the tabs, like it used to be but just on the other side. How can I move the button section to the left side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string "close,minimize,maximize:"
```

turns

[image: right]

to

[image: left]

Comment: Feature requests to set this as default: [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21438), [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1594111)

Comment: This command has no effect in Chromium 53.0.2785.143 on Loki (64bit) - any other suggestion? For now I use system titlebar but that extra bar bothers me (one program having close button on the right bothers me more so I have to bear with that extra bar until I find working solution)..

Comment: fixed in chromium 55

Comment: broken again in chromium 59 #(

Comment: This has been fixed upstream in chromium 61 and above, which now uses native GTK. However the buttons look correctly only on my other computer with Gnome, where i haven't tried any of these tweaks. On elementary after the upgrade I have no buttons at all (only the profile button on the right). Does anybody know how to get them back / reset these settings?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could run: `gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string "close:maximize"` to maintain consistency with the default elementary window controls.